# Put constant text inside EditText which should be non-editable - Android

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, material-design, material-components-android

I want to have constant text inside editText like:

```
http://<here_user_can_write>
```

User should not be able to delete any chars from "`http://`", I searched about this and found this:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
            int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
            return src.length() < 1 ? dst.subSequence(dstart, dend) : "";
        }
    }
});
```

but I don't know whether it restricts user to not delete any chars from *start to end* limit. I also could not understand use of Spanned class.

One way would be a good choice if we can put a `TextView` inside `EditText` but I don't think it is possible in Android since both are Views, is it possible?

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19789317/983741

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Did u try this method?

```
final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

edt.setText("http://");
Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());


edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!s.toString().startsWith("http://")){
                edt.setText("http://");
                Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: It's safer to use `startsWith` rather than `contains`, to avoid user moving the cursor position and type anything before the constant.

Comment: but when  deletes it without moving the hand from delete button the text is removed.how can I solve?

Comment: i cant set the hint now..help me

Comment: Also you can extend EditText and override protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) method, and in this way prevent even selecting constant text

Comment: I have quite similar requirement but i want text "KG" in back always.when user type text.How to achieve this.please help.

Answer (score 59):

As of version [1.2.0-alpha01](http://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases) of [material design library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android), prefix and suffix is supported for text fields:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:prefixText="Price: "
        app:prefixTextAppearance="..."
        app:prefixTextColor="..."
        app:suffixText="Dollar"
        app:suffixTextColor="..."
        app:suffixTextAppearance="...">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText .../>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The only downside in my opinion is that the **suffix** is fixed at the end of the text field and there is no option to make it flow with the input text. You can vote on [this issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/750) for that.

Comment: Here prefix is not fixed at the beginning of a text

Comment: If anyone has a problem with alignment of prefix and edit text this link could be useful: [github link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/773#issuecomment-603759649)

Comment: @KonstantinKonopko add this code in your dimen.xml:    `<dimen name="material_input_text_to_prefix_suffix_padding">0dp</dimen>`

Answer (score 16):

That's how you can actually do it with an `InputFilter`:

```
final String prefix = "http://"
editText.setText(prefix);

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
      @Override
      public CharSequence filter(final CharSequence source, final int start,
          final int end, final Spanned dest, final int dstart, final int dend) {
        final int newStart = Math.max(prefix.length(), dstart);
        final int newEnd = Math.max(prefix.length(), dend);
        if (newStart != dstart || newEnd != dend) {
          final SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(dest);
          builder.replace(newStart, newEnd, source);
          if (source instanceof Spanned) {
            TextUtils.copySpansFrom(
                (Spanned) source, 0, source.length(), null, builder, newStart);
          }
          Selection.setSelection(builder, newStart + source.length());
          return builder;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
});
```

If you also want the prefix to be not selectable you can add the following code.

```
final SpanWatcher watcher = new SpanWatcher() {
  @Override
  public void onSpanAdded(final Spannable text, final Object what,
      final int start, final int end) {
    // Nothing here.
  }

  @Override
  public void onSpanRemoved(final Spannable text, final Object what, 
      final int start, final int end) {
    // Nothing here.
  }

  @Override
  public void onSpanChanged(final Spannable text, final Object what, 
      final int ostart, final int oend, final int nstart, final int nend) {
    if (what == Selection.SELECTION_START) {
      if (nstart < prefix.length()) {
        final int end = Math.max(prefix.length(), Selection.getSelectionEnd(text));
        Selection.setSelection(text, prefix.length(), end);
      }
    } else if (what == Selection.SELECTION_END) {
      final int start = Math.max(prefix.length(), Selection.getSelectionEnd(text));
      final int end = Math.max(start, nstart);
      if (end != nstart) {
        Selection.setSelection(text, start, end);
      }
    }
  }
};

editText.getText().setSpan(watcher, 0, 0, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 10):

There was a slight problem with @Rajitha Siriwardena's answer.
It assumes that the entire string except the suffix has been deleted before the suffix is meaning if you have the string

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

and try to delete any part of `http://` you will delete `stackoverflow.com/` resulting in only `http://`.

I also added a check incase the user tries to input before the prefix.

```
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
     String prefix = "http://";
     if (!s.toString().startsWith(prefix)) {
         String cleanString;
         String deletedPrefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
         if (s.toString().startsWith(deletedPrefix)) {
             cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll(deletedPrefix, "");
         } else {
             cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll(prefix, "");
         }
         editText.setText(prefix + cleanString);
         editText.setSelection(prefix.length());
    }
}
```

Note: this doesn't handle the case where the user tries to edit the prefix itself only before and after.

Answer (score 7):

> Taken from Ali Muzaffar's blog, see [the original post](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/adding-a-prefix-to-an-edittext-2a17a62c77e1) for more details.

Use custom `EditText` View to draw the prefix text and add padding according to the prefix text size:

```
public class PrefixEditText extends EditText {

private String mPrefix = "$"; // add your prefix here for example $
private Rect mPrefixRect = new Rect(); // actual prefix size

public PrefixEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    getPaint().getTextBounds(mPrefix, 0, mPrefix.length(), mPrefixRect);
    mPrefixRect.right += getPaint().measureText(" "); // add some offset

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawText(mPrefix, super.getCompoundPaddingLeft(), getBaseline(), getPaint());
}

@Override
public int getCompoundPaddingLeft() {
    return super.getCompoundPaddingLeft() + mPrefixRect.width();
}
}
```

Comment: Hey Vishal, next time you copy a code from somebody's blog (or anywhere from the internet), please remember to link to the source.

Answer (score 6):

You had it almost right, try

```
private final String PREFIX="http://";

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int
                    dend) {
                return dstart<PREFIX.length()?dest.subSequence(dstart,dend):null;
            }
        }});
```

Comment: The EditText field stopped receiving any input. can't type anything in it. I believe this solution is not working anymore.

Answer (score 5):

**CODE TO ADD CUSTOM PREFIX TO YOUR EDITTEXT (PREFIX NOT EDITABLE)**

Code from Medium by Ali Muzaffar

```
public class PrefixEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
    float originalLeftPadding = -1;

    public PrefixEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PrefixEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PrefixEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        calculatePrefix();
    }

    private void calculatePrefix() {
        if (originalLeftPadding == -1) {
            String prefix = (String) getTag();
            float[] widths = new float[prefix.length()];
            getPaint().getTextWidths(prefix, widths);
            float textWidth = 0;
            for (float w : widths) {
                textWidth += w;
            }
            originalLeftPadding = getCompoundPaddingLeft();
            setPadding((int) (textWidth + originalLeftPadding),
                getPaddingRight(), getPaddingTop(),
                getPaddingBottom());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        String prefix = (String) getTag();
        canvas.drawText(prefix, originalLeftPadding, getLineBounds(0, null), getPaint());
    }
}
```

And XML

```
<com.yourClassPath.PrefixEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:tag="€ " />
```

Comment: Make sure you use right class path in your xml file.
com.alimuzaffar.customwidgets.PrefixEditText - if you use this, your app will crush.

Comment: this is not working in Nougat and in other OS it's working fine, can you please let me know , how can we resolve this in Nougat?

Comment: The answer written right before yours points to the same Medium post.

Comment: @SebastianPalma at the time i wrote my answer there was no link to the blog.
The answer was edited.

Comment: How would you set text on this edittext? .setText() does not seem to be working.

Comment: how to change color for tag(prefix value)?

Answer (score 4):

An easy to use Kotlin extension function for this purpose

```
fun EditText.stickPrefix(prefix: String) {
    this.addTextChangedListener(afterTextChanged = {
        if (!it.toString().startsWith(prefix) && it?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
            this.setText(prefix + this.text)
            this.setSelection(this.length())

        }
    })
}
//someEditText.stickPrefix("+")
```

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm reviving an old post but I want to share with the community that I have struggled with this topic these days and I found that placing a `TextView` over the `EditText` is not only perfectly doable (to respond to the second part of the question), much more in this case when the constant text is needed in the starting position, but preferable, too. Moreover the cursor won't even move before the "mutable" text at all, which is an elegant effect.
I prefer this solution because it doesn't add workload and complexity to my app with listeners and whatsoever.

Here's a sample code of my solution:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:text="http://" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        android:paddingStart="choose an appropriate padding" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

By enclosing the views in a `RelativeLayout` they will be overlapped.
The trick here is playing with the `android:paddingStart` property of the `EditText`, to make the text start just right after the `TextView`, while `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and `android:layout_marginStart="3dp"` properties of the `TextView` make sure that its text is correctly aligned with text inputted and with the start of the underlying line of the `EditText` (or at least this happens when using a Material themed one).

Answer (score 3):

I made Kotlin extension function for adding prefix to `EditText`

```
fun EditText.addPrefix(prefix: String) {
        var text = ""
        var isPrefixModified = false
        val formattedPrefix = "$prefix "
        var lastCharSequence: CharSequence? = null

        val setEditText: () -> Unit = {
            setText(text)
            Selection.setSelection(editableText, text.length)
        }

        this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
                val newText = editable.toString()

                when {
                    isPrefixModified -> {
                        isPrefixModified = false
                        setEditText()
                    }
                    isTryingToDeletePrefix(newText) -> {
                        setEditText()
                    }
                    isNewInput(newText) -> {
                        text = "$formattedPrefix$newText"
                        setEditText()
                    }
                    else -> {
                        text = newText
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence?, start: Int,
                                           count: Int, after: Int) {
                charSequence?.let {
                    if (it != lastCharSequence && it.isNotEmpty() && start <= prefix.length) {
                        isPrefixModified = true
                    }
                    lastCharSequence = charSequence
                }
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence?, start: Int,
                                       before: Int, count: Int) {
                // Ignore
            }

            private fun isTryingToDeletePrefix(newText: String) =
                    text.isNotEmpty() && newText.length < text.length && isNewInput(newText)

            private fun isNewInput(newText: String) = !newText.contains(formattedPrefix)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Any way to update PreFix? I want to change after user perform some task

Comment: I think you can try remove old one and new one, just make some adjustments to code

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution how to make prefix not-editable and how to save text if you try to remove prefix. That's very close to @Rajitha Siriwardena answer. All you missed is to save text before any changes applied. It will be restored in afterTextChanged(...).

Code:

```
final String prefix = "http://";
editText.setText(prefix);
Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    String text;
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        text = charSequence.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (!editable.toString().startsWith(prefix)) {
            editText.setText(text);
            Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), editText.getText().length());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is basically to add prefix "+91" to your edit text field of phone number.

1.Add this code to oncreate() of activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

   // Write other things......//

   etPhoneNumber.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{getPhoneFilter(),newInputFilter.LengthFilter(13)});

    etPhoneNumber.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                if (etPhoneNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    etPhoneNumber.setText("+91");
                    Selection.setSelection(etPhoneNumber.getText(), etPhoneNumber.getText().length());                    }
            } else {
                if (etPhoneNumber.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("+91")) {
                    etPhoneNumber.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{});
                    etPhoneNumber.setText("");
                    etPhoneNumber.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{getPhoneFilter(),new InputFilter.LengthFilter(13)});

                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

2.Declare a method called getPhoneFilter()

```
    private InputFilter getPhoneFilter() {

    Selection.setSelection(etPhoneNumber.getText(), etPhoneNumber.getText().length());

    etPhoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!s.toString().startsWith("+91")){
                if (etPhoneNumber.getFilters() != null && etPhoneNumber.getFilters().length > 0) {
                    etPhoneNumber.setText("+91");
                    Selection.setSelection(etPhoneNumber.getText(), etPhoneNumber.getText().length());
                }
            }
        }
    });

     // Input filter to restrict user to enter only digits..
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {

                if (!String.valueOf(getString(R.string.digits_number)).contains(String.valueOf(source.charAt(i)))) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

3.declare "digits_number" in your values file

```
    <string name="digits_number">1234567890+</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [@demaksee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/755313/demaksee) comment. I extend EditText and override function onSelectionChanged. So user even can`t edit prefix. Very simple and useful.
Kotlin:

```
private var prefix : String? = ""

override fun onSelectionChanged(selStart: Int, selEnd: Int) {
    if (prefix != null && prefix!!.isNotBlank()) {
        var finalStart = selStart
        var finalEnd = selEnd

        val prefixLength = prefix!!.length
        if (prefixLength > selStart) {
            finalStart = prefixLength
        }

        if (prefixLength > selEnd) {
            finalEnd = prefixLength
        }

        if (finalStart == selStart && finalEnd == selEnd) {
            super.onSelectionChanged(finalStart, finalEnd)
        } else {
            val startWithPrefix = text?.startsWith(prefix ?: "") ?: prefix.isNullOrBlank()
            if (!startWithPrefix) {
                setText(prefix)
            }

            setSelection(finalStart, finalEnd)
        }
    }
}

public fun setPrefix(prefix: String) {
    editText.setText(prefix)
    editText.setSelection(prefix.length)
    this.prefix = prefix
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less efficient solution that should handle all cases for when characters OR words are deleted/inserted in OR around the prefix.

```
prefix = "http://"
extra = "ahhttp://"
differencePrefix(prefix, extra) = "aht"
```

Code:

```
public static String differencePrefix(String prefix, String extra) {
    if (extra.length() < prefix.length()) return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder eb = new StringBuilder();
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < extra.length(); i++) {
        if (i >= prefix.length()) {
            while(p < extra.length()) {
                eb.append(extra.charAt(p));
                p++;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (p >= extra.length()) break;
        char pchar = extra.charAt(p);
        char ichar = prefix.charAt(i);
        while(pchar != ichar) {
            //check if char was deleted
            int c = i + 1;
            if (c < prefix.length()) {
                char cchar = prefix.charAt(c);
                if (cchar == pchar) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            sb.append(pchar);
            p++;
            if (p >= extra.length()) break;
            pchar = extra.charAt(p);
        }
        p++;
    }

    return eb.toString() + sb.toString();
}
```

You can use it like this

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String input = s.toString();
        if (!input.startsWith(prefix)) {
            String extra = differencePrefix(prefix, input);
            String newInput = prefix + extra;
            editText.setText(newInput);
            editText.setSelection(newInput.length());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    EditText msg=new EditText(getContext());
                msg.setSingleLine(true);
                msg.setSingleLine();
                msg.setId(View.generateViewId());
                msg.measure(0,0);



                TextView count=new TextView(getContext());
                count.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
                count.setText("20");
                count.setPadding(0,0,(int)Abstract.getDIP(getContext(),10),0);
                count.measure(0,0);
float tenPIX =TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,10,getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

 msg.setPadding((int)tenPIX,(int)tenPIX,(int)(int)tenPIX+count.getMeasuredWidth(),(int)tenPIX);


                RelativeLayout ll1=new RelativeLayout(getContext());
                ll1.addView(msg,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

LayoutParams countlp=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                countlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_END,msg.getId());
                countlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE,msg.getId());
                ll1.addView(count,countlp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below works for me. It handles cases when the user edits the prefix, deletes it, inserts text from the buffer, changes the selected text. If the user changes the prefix, the focus moves to the end of the prefix.

```
    final String prefix = "http://";
    final String[] aLastText = {prefix};
    et.setText(prefix);
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable sNew) {

            if (!sNew.toString().startsWith(prefix)) {
                String sLast = aLastText[0];
                boolean isRemoving = sNew.length() < sLast.length();

                int start;
                int end = sNew.length() - 1;
                for (start = 0; start < sLast.length() && start < sNew.length(); start++) {
                    if (sLast.charAt(start) != sNew.charAt(start)) 
                        break;
                }
                int k = sLast.length() - 1;
                for (; end >= start && k >= 0; end--, k--) {
                    if (sLast.charAt(k) != sNew.charAt(end)) 
                        break;
                }
                String sEdited = sNew.toString().substring(start, ++end);
                k += isRemoving ? 1 : 0;
                k = k < prefix.length() ? prefix.length() : k;
                String sSuffix = sLast.substring(k, sLast.length());

                et.setText(prefix + sEdited + sSuffix);
                et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - sSuffix.length());
            }
            aLastText[0] = et.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

Examples:

ht5tp://localhost, 5http://localhost, http:/5/localhost -> http://5localhost

http:localhost -> http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is to add some changes on Rajitha Siriwardena code :

**First**, put text on the `Edittext` or `TextInputEditText` xml layout :
`android:text="http://"`
the purpose is to test the if condition on the first attempt

**Second**,
test the condition with if like this

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
if (!s.toString().startsWith("http://")) {
    etPhone.setText("http://");
    etPhone.setSelection(etPhone.length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am baffled by the complex answers posted. More easier way will be to add a textview with code as text as a prefix and put some elevation. This way, you will much finer control over the designing of the code("+91"). Here's an example of the same.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 

android:id="@+id/mobile_bottom_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/card_with_top_radius"
android:elevation="12dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dim_18"
app:flow_verticalAlign="bottom"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">


  

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/code"
    style="@style/color_333333_text_14_roboto_regular_venus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dim_16"
    android:text="+91"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/number"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/number"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/number" />


<com.gradeup.baseM.view.custom.TabletEditText
    android:id="@+id/number"
    style="@style/color_333333_text_12_roboto_medium_venus"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dim_16"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_17"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_16"
    android:background="@drawable/e6e6e6_4dp_curved_border_white_bg"
    android:hint="@string/enter_mobile_number"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="10"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/dim_17"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/dim_50"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:textColorHint="@color/color_999999_8799ae"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subTitle">



</com.gradeup.baseM.view.custom.TabletEditText>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Things to keep in mind :-

- Adjust editText paddingStart attribute according to your need.
- Put some elevation in code TextView.