# Prefilled text in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to add a prefilled text like country code in an edittext for mobile number. Prefilled text should be uneditable. I have tried it by overriding onSelectionChanged(). Is there any better solution?

```
    final EditText editText = new EditText(this){
        int prevSelection;
        @Override
        protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
            if(selStart < 4){
                setSelection(prevSelection);
                return;
            }
            prevSelection = selStart;
        }
    };
```

Comment: setText and set editable to false?

Comment: editText.setHint("")

Comment: or just set the text and then set enable false

Comment: Post your onSelectionChanged() code, because it should work (you basically want to have a prefix, right?)

Comment: I want a part of text which is pre-filled like country code non editable and rest  to be editable.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195207/put-constant-text-inside-edittext-which-should-be-non-editable-android

Comment: if that is the case take another `TextView` before `EditText` . at end it is not editable

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
editText.setText("This is a prefilled text"); // This to set prefilled text
editText.setFocusable(false);                 // This disable editing
```

OR

```
editText.setHint("This is sample country code"); // this is the hint
```

Hint is something like this:

[image]

Comment: I think he just wants a prefix to always be there, and not the disable edition.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final EditText editText = new EditText(this){
        int prevSelection;
        @Override
        protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
            if (!editText.getText().toString().startsWith("pre filled text")){
                editText.setText("pre filled text" + editText.getText().toString());
            }

        }
    };
```

The function will check if the EditText start with the "preFilled" text, if not it will add it to the beginning of the EditText

Answer (score 0):

Implement `android.text.TextWatcher` in the `Activity` or `Fragment` containing the `EditText`.

In the `afterTextChanged` method add the country code to the beginning of the text.

It would be good to check if the country code is already filled in before adding it. Be careful not to end in an infinite loop here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
 editText.setText("country code" + editText.getText().toString());
```