# Android EditText help: uneditable text beside EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to have an edittext that has an uneditable text beside it (on the left, the beginning of the EditText). Just like this one, How do I go with this?

[image: EditText with a text beside it]

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195207/put-constant-text-inside-edittext-which-should-be-non-editable-android), you may get clue

Comment: The text you want to display in your edit text is static or dynamic ?

Comment: static text!

Thanks Ichigo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final EditText edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

edt.setText("Speed");
Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());


edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!s.toString().contains("http://")){
                edt.setText("http://");
                Selection.setSelection(edt.getText(), edt.getText().length());

            }

        }
    });
```

try this....

Answer (score 0):

[Put constant text inside EditText which should be non-editable - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195207/put-constant-text-inside-edittext-which-should-be-non-editable-android)

I found this useful for those who wanted it. I haven't applied it yet but this would work, right?