# how to make a part of textview editable

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-custom-view, anko

First I'm using Anko library, Kotlin, Java in my project.
I have an android app that test skills in French so I want to make a part of Textview editable its something like this (Solo Learn):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfric.png
I try :

```
je mang$ une pomme
```

then split String with $ and add editText in place of $ but it's not a good idea 
using web view also it's not a good idea even its work
thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks more like `textView editText textView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add **addTextChangedListener** to *EditText* view and add **prefix** or **suffix**, you need to be non-editable.

Check this previous question also ->

[Put constant text inside EditText which should be non-editable - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195207/put-constant-text-inside-edittext-which-should-be-non-editable-android)