# Textwacher loops after calling append

Tags: android

I have a problem with TextWatcher. After i am done editing, i want to append " kg" string. But after i try to edit editView, it loops and my app crashes. Can somebody help me? Thanks

> 

```
weight = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        weight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                editable.append(" kg");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14195571/9495357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage this with an if statement but I think that it can down in better way

```
    weight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            if(!editable.getText().contains("kg"))
               editable.append(" kg");
        }
    });
```

Comment: With few changes your idea works good. I couldnt use editable, because it doesnt have getText method. I just changed editable with weight and it works. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its looping because setting the text calls afterTextChanged. What you could do is remove the text watcher, change the text, then re-add the text watcher.

Comment: Tried your idea, it no longer loops but every time i press any key it adds " kg".

Comment: The messy solution i can think of is to set the editable to `editable.text.replaceFirst(" kg", "")` and then append " kg" to the end of that

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. **Remove the TextWatcher temporarily**
2. Do your changes to your content
3. **Add the TextWatcher again**

   ```
   weight.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (editable.toString().contains("kg")) return
            weight.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            editable.append(" kg");
            weight.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    });
   ```

Comment: Tried this already. Every time i press a key ( letter, number, backspace or any other) it adds " kg".

Comment: this edit would likely cause it to add kg the first time you enter a character and then never add kg again