# The text of the edittext can't modified

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-applicationinfo

guys I want to keep the edittext text can't modified or cleaned by the user like i want `https://www` to be fixed no one can clean it but the user can write in the edittext

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter a website"
            android:text="https://www."
            android:id="@+id/et_web"/>
```

Comment: try adding  android:editable="true"

Comment: This might help you. [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195207/put-constant-text-inside-edittext-which-should-be-non-editable-android)