# How to disable to edit some part of text in EditText?

Tags: kotlin, android-edittext

When user open a dialog, an edittext appears with a text. How can I block the user to edit .db part. I want user to only change the test100Mb text. How can I do this ?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put constant text inside EditText which should be non-editable - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195207/put-constant-text-inside-edittext-which-should-be-non-editable-android)

Answer (score 0):

U can do it without showing the .db to the user